# TypeError: got multiple values for argument 'dictionary'

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror, lda

i read other questioned which are asked about this error earlier.but still i am not getting where i am making a mistake.when i call the function i got this error. i am very new in this forum ,any help in solving my problem will be appreciated.here is my code

```
def lda_train(self, documents):
        # create dictionary
        dictionary= corpora.Dictionary(documents)
        dictionary.compactify()
        dictionary.save(self.DICTIONARY_FILE)  # store the dictionary, for future reference
        print ("============ Dictionary Generated and Saved ============")

        ############# Create Corpus##########################

        corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(text) for text in documents]
        print('Number of unique tokens: %d' % len(dictionary))
        print('Number of documents: %d' % len(corpus))
        return dictionary,corpus

def compute_coherence_values(dictionary,corpus,documents,  limit, start=2, step=3):
        num_topics = 10
        coherence_values = []
        model_list = []
        for num_topics in range(start, limit, step):
            lda_model = gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel(corpus=corpus,id2word=dictionary, num_topics=num_topics,  random_state=100, alpha='auto')
            model_list.append(model)
            coherencemodel = CoherenceModel(model=model, texts=texts, dictionary=dictionary, coherence='c_v')
            coherence_values.append(coherencemodel.get_coherence())
        return model_list, coherence_values
```

when i call this function in main by using this code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    limit=40
    start=2
    step=6
    obj = LDAModel()
    lda_input = get_lda_input_from_corpus_folder('./dataset/TRAIN')
    dictionary,corpus =obj.lda_train(lda_input)
    model_list, coherence_values = obj.compute_coherence_values(dictionary=dictionary,corpus=corpus, texts=lda_input,  start=2, limit=40, step=6)
```

i receive an error message :

```
 model_list, coherence_values=obj.compute_coherence_values(dictionary=dictionary,corpus=corpus, texts=lda_input,  start=2, limit=40, step=6) 
TypeError: compute_coherence_values() got multiple values for argument 'dictionary'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR**

Change

`def compute_coherence_values(dictionary, corpus, documents, limit, start=2, step=3)`

to

`def compute_coherence_values(self, dictionary, corpus, documents, limit, start=2, step=3)`

You forgot to pass `self` as the first argument so the instance is being passed as `dictionary` argument, but you also pass `dictionary` as an explicit keyword argument.

This behavior can be easily reproduced:

```
class Foo:
   def bar(a):
       pass

Foo().bar(a='a')
TypeError: bar() got multiple values for argument 'a'
```

Comment: thank you for replying,i m still not getting.i should just pass the self argument or any other changes too?

Comment: model_list, coherence_values = obj.compute_coherence_values(dictionary=dic,corpus=corpus, texts=lda_input,  start=2, limit=40, step=6)
TypeError: compute_coherence_values() got an unexpected keyword argument 'texts'

Comment: @ameera Well, there is no `texts` argument in `compute_coherence_values` definition....